# Configuring WordPress with NGINX Proxy Manager for SSL locally

Tags: wordpress, nginx-reverse-proxy, self-hosting

## Description

I'm having trouble using HTTPS/SSL with WordPress and NGINX Proxy Manager. Currently, I set my site address and WordPress address to the domain without any HTTPS and it sort of works with the NPM certificate except that it's unable to load images/assets. The problem is when I change the site/WordPress address I am unable to access my website anymore, even though it was working previously without it. I've tried looking for solutions but for some reason, it isn't well documented and my only solid lead was to a site that is no longer up.

### Specs

- Home server running VMware ESXi with multiple Linux VMs.
- NGINX Proxy manager running in a docker container
- WordPress on a separate Ubuntu VM with the LAMP stack